# How do I convert this from a while loop into a for loop?

Tags: ruby

How would I make this `while` loop into a `for` loop?

```
ten_things = "Apples Oranges Crows Telephone Light Sugar"
stuff = ten_things.split(' ')
puts "Wait there are not 10 things in that list. Let's fix that."
more_stuff = ["Day", "Night", "Song", "Frisbee", "Corn", "Banana", "Girl", "Boy"]
while stuff.length != 10
  next_one = more_stuff.pop
  puts "Adding: #{next_one}"
  stuff.push(next_one)
  puts "There are #{stuff.length} items now."
end
```

I tried and got an infinite loop

Comment: why not `stuff = (ten_things.split(' ') + ["Day", "Night", "Song", "Frisbee", "Corn", "Banana", "Girl", "Boy"]).first(10)` No loop needed at all. Obviously I have no idea what the rest of the code looks like.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why don't you tell us what you're trying to do overall, instead of asking us how to pop from one array and push onto another?

Comment: Looks contrived - like a homework type question.

Comment: @engneersmnky, just because.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you would bother making it a `for` loop when a `while` or `until` loop is meant for it.

However, this will work:

```
ten_things = "Apples Oranges Crows Telephone Light Sugar"

puts "Wait there are not 10 things in that list. Let's fix that."

stuff = ten_things.split(' ')
more_stuff = ["Day", "Night", "Song", "Frisbee", "Corn", "Banana", "Girl", "Boy"]

# using math to make sure there's 10 items
i = stuff.length
for i in i...10
    next_one = more_stuff.pop
    puts "Adding: #{next_one}"
    stuff.push(next_one)
    puts "There are #{stuff.length} items now."
end
```

Comment: Went ahead and wrote it with `for` just because.

Comment: As long as you change that condition so it will exit if `more_stuff` is less than 10.  Otherwise that loop will never end.

Comment: It will, because it goes on a range from `stuff.length` to 10. Range does the job of a condition.

Comment: @engineersmnky Sorry, I replied before he added the for loop and was referring to OP's original while loop.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom understood comment removed. Looping still doesn't make sense to me in this case when we can just combine the arrays and take the first 10 items

Comment: @engineersmnky Agreed.

Comment: @engineersmnky yeah your way is better. Typical ruby with so many ways to do something.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
array_name.each { |item|
    break if stuff.length > 10
    stuff.push(item)
}
```